# oracle failsafe - how to start instance in nomount

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle-fail-safe

Using Oracle Failsafe, how can a instance be started up in nomount mode?

If the instance is shutdown via sqlplus, the windows cluster manager just starts it up again. If the instance is shutdown via windows cluster manager, I'm unable to connect to it via sqlplus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Shutdown instance in Cluster Manager (Right click, "Take Offline" or however you choose to do it)
2. Bring up Windows Services (Start->Run->Services.MSC) on the clustered server
3. Start the Oracle service for the instance you want
4. Now you can do whatever you like in SQL*Plus (Cluster Manager will still show it as down no matter what you do at this point)

So, if step 3 brings the Oracle instance up to "Open" you can do a shutdown immediate etc and then open it nomount.

HTH

Comment: Cheers, step two was the all important bit I was missing.